# underscore.jsのテンプレート機能が上手く動作しない

Tags: javascript, html5, node.js

## 前提

underscore.jsを用いてhtmlにテンプレートを作成し、動的に
htmlの内容を変更させたいと考えています。

## 現在の問題

下記ソースコードのように書いたのですが、上手くテンプレートが
htmlに反映されません。
何が間違っているのか、お伺いしたいです。

## HTMLソースコード

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src = jsファイルがおいてある場所></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">
 <div class = "row">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="bootcards-list col-sm-6">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="list-group">
  <script id = "temp" type = "text/template">
 /*テンプレート*/
 <a class="list-group-item" id = "list_<%- data.name %> "href="#<%- data.name %>" onclick="comp('#<%- data.name %>')">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-1">
            <img src="<%- data.img %>">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%- data.name %></h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"><%- data.text %></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p class="list-group-item-text"><%- data.text %></p>
            <p class="list-group-item-text"><%- data.text %></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      </script>
・・・
</body>
```

## JSソースコード

```
$(function(){
  var tmplSrc = $('#temp');
  var source = {
   data:[
  {
  "name":"aaa",
  "text":"ddd",
  "img":"cccc"
 },
 ]
};
var complied = _.template(tmplSrc,source);
$('body').append(complied);
})
```

Comment: `$`について明示されていませんが、jQueryであるならば変数`tmplSrc`は現状ではjQueryオブジェクトになっています。対してtemplate関数はsignatureが[`_.template(templateString, [settings])`](http://underscorejs.org/#template)となっていて、第一引数には文字列を期待しているように見えます。

Comment: $はJQueryのつもりで書きました。オブジェクトをわたしてましたね…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

正直言って、ツッコミどころが満載です笑
とりあえず気付いた点を挙げると・・・

- dataは配列で渡しているのに、テンプレートはオブジェクト（{}）として扱っている
- template関数の使い方が間違っている（**templateが返す関数に**データを渡さなければならない）
- htmlエレメントの属性の指定にスペースが入っている （ex. script id = "temp" type = "text/template"）
- コピペしただけでは動かないコードで質問している（誰も回答してくれませんよ）
- 「どう上手くいかないのか」についての説明がない

とりあえず動くサンプルを作成しましたので、そちらを見ながらどこがおかしいのか確認してみてください。
https://codepen.io/itmammoth/pen/XgjXov?editors=1010

参考： Underscoreのヘルプ(http://underscorejs.org/#template)